# Gatsby fails to generate CSS file without error

Tags: gatsby

I recently got an upgraded laptop for work. I ran through all the set up for our build environment (install Node, run npm install, install gatsby) and cloned our repo locally.

When I went to build, however, using `gatsby build --prefix-links`, I got "Generating CSS" and then nothing. No error and no actual CSS file anywhere. I'm dropped back to my command prompt. There's also no /public folder created.

I've tried moving the repo to another folder, uninstalling and reinstalling gatsby, but still getting this behavior. I've verified on my old laptop that building works.

Our team had this all set up by someone who is no longer available, and I have no familiarity with Gatsby. I've searched on Google and here, but I can't find an example that anyone else has had this issue.

Hoping you all can help me out somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a lock file.

Comment: when I look for lock files, I see many. I've seen other questions about a file called "package-lock.json" but when I search on that, I find many, many copies. I'm also not sure what I'm supposed to do with this file.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your dependencies, my best guess would be that you are running Gatsby v2 on your new machine and the app is using a previous version. You can either install the same version on your new machine (not sure if possible) or upgrade the app to the latest version of Gatsby, which I assume is what you want to do. The docs are here https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/migrating-from-v1-to-v2/ .